# How to use 'unsquashfs' with lzma?

Tags: squashfs

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I want to unsquash an lzma image. I have done

```
sudo apt-get squashfs-tools
```

Now, when I do

```
unsquashfs <squashed_image_filename>
```

I get

```
Filesystem uses lzma compression, this is unsupported by this version
```

I know my squashed image is lzma. How do I install support for lzma? I have downloaded the squashfs-tools from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/squashfs/files/

It is my understanding that after extracting that tarball, I need to `cd` into `squashfs4.2/squashfs-tools` and edit the `Makefile` by uncommenting the line `LZMA_XZ_SUPPORT = 1`. Then I just need to run `make`.

That does not work for me. I get the error:

```
gzip_wrapper.c:23:18: fatal error: zlib.: No such file or directory
```

I think I need to install `lzma-devel` and `xz-devel`. I have tried this and been Googling for a couple hours and haven't gotten anywhere or found any solid instructions that show how this should work. Can anyone who has done this help me out?  **I am new to desktop Linux** so if you could be fairly verbose in your instructions that would be appreciated.

Comment: are you familiar with non-desktop Linux?

Comment: which version of squashfs-tools have you downloaded?

Comment: The Ubuntu packages are `lzma-dev` or `liblzma-dev` not "devel".

Comment: @qdii I'm most comfortable with embedded Linux. And I download squashfs-tools 4.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @msw, I figured out the package names for Ubuntu. Thank you! Here's the full steps for someone in the future.

Get source here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/squashfs/

```
# sudo apt-get install lzma-dev
# sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
# tar -zxvf squashfs4.2.tar.gz
# cd squashfs4.2/squashfs-tools: Edit Makefile and uncomment this line "LZMA_XZ_SUPPORT = 1"
# make
# sudo make install
# sudo unsquashfs <path/lzma_filename_to_unsquash>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here looking for squashfs with lzma support, it seems that in Ubuntu 22.10:

- The kernel (5.19.0) does *not* support mounting LZMA-compressed squashfs images:

  ```
  Filesystem uses "lzma" compression. This is not supported
  ```
- The `unsquashfs` tool from the `squashfs-tools` (version 1:4.5.1-1) *does* support LZMA without any special options.